# Select List Change Event Triggers When User Types Characters

Tags: jquery

I have a select list that I have hooked up to a change event..

```
  $('.ddlApplications').change(function () { alert('Hi'); })
```

If you put focus on the select and start typing this event is fired. I want to be able to force the user to select an option from the select and Not be able to type inside the select. How can I disable (or not trigger the change event) when the user types in the select box?

I tried disabling the select but then you cannot select any of the options, so this wont work..

```
 $('.ddlApplications').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: How do you type anything in a select element? Tried this with a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yYkUd/), and the change event only fires when the value changes ?

Comment: it is in your html. please paste that code.

Comment: @adeneo: You can type the first letter(s) to quickly go to an item in the list.

Comment: @pimvdb - if that's the problem, I have the solution :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to select an option with the keys, just disable the keys?

```
$('.ddlApplications').on({
    keydown: function() {
        return false;
    },
    change: function() {
        alert('Hi');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yYkUd/1/)